# Does every globally hyperbolic spacetime admit a maximal slicing?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

A globally hyperbolic spacetime is (roughly speaking) one with the topology of $\Sigma \times \mathbb{R}$ and a physically reasonable causal structure (no closed causal curves, that sort of thing) and can be foliated by spacelike hypersurfaces. A spacelike hypersurface is maximal if its mean extrinsic curvature is zero (meaning that the shape operator $\chi (v)=\nabla_v n$, measuring the bending of the timeline unit normal to the hypersurface in directions within the surface, has eigenvalues that sum to zero).

My question is: can every globally hyperbolic spacetime be foliated by maximal spacelike hypersurfaces, or are there are conditions on when this is possible? (And if so, what are those conditions?)